# I am unable to get Coordinates from ajax to the google map script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

This my places.php file Here I am getting my coordinates from the database, I have checked this by echoing it's just fine, Also my connection to the database is just fine. Here I have made a self-executing function that repeats itself in an infinite loop and whenever the values will be changed or updated in the database my marker position will also updated. The code is very simple but looks like my ajax success variables aren't working.

```
include 'connection.php';
$myque = mysqli_query($con, 'Select * from places where id=1');
$gtloc = mysqli_fetch_array($myque);
$lati = $gtloc['lati'];
$long = $gtloc['longi'];


echo lati.",".$long;
//echo $long;
}
```

Here I am receiving the ajax success response and assigning it to a variable  but it doesn't work.

Inserting Direct Coordinates shows the map but I need to make the marker responsive to database coordinates without refreshing the page. Inserting my variable to lat & long just and the map totally disappears

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>

        function test(){ 
        //ajax call goes here

    $.ajax({
        url: "places.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        data:  {"id": 1},
        success : function(value){
                    //alert("RESPONSE");
                var data = value.split(",");
                var latitude  = (data[0]);
                var longitude  = (data[1]); 
            }      
        });


      window.setTimeout(function(){
        test();
      }, 1500);
        }
            $(document).ready(function(){
            test();
            });


      </script>
      <script>
          function initMap() {
      var uluru = {lat: latitude  , lng: longitude };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: uluru
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
      });
      }
      </script>

      </head>
      <body>
    <script></script>
      <h2>My Places</h2>
      <div  id="map" style="height: 700px;width: 100%;"></div>
      <!--map script --> 
      <!-- / Map Script-->
      <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYBZxCetgqbsCQU3mxZ622GwNdSglEVN4&callback=initMap"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I only know that coordinates should be stored as BSON, not regular JSON.

Comment: because latitude and longitude are scoped to the Ajax call and you are assuming it would come back before init fires....

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that those are string values. Try to make then lat/long float variables...

```
var lat = parseFloat(latitude);
var long = parseFloat(longitude);
```

In your example:

```
    success : function(value){
                //alert("RESPONSE");
            var data = value.split(",");
            var latitude  = (data[0]);
            var longitude  = (data[1]); 
        }
```

Just add parseFloat like this:

```
        var latitude  = parseFloat(data[0]);
        var longitude  = parseFloat(data[1]);
```

I think it would solve it.

Comment: It did solved my issue, but i had to flash my Map's function as well to update  my Marker location. now every 3 seconds my ajax sync with database and checks the values, also my map flashes to change the variable value according to ajax response.

Comment: that quick flash on map is really annoying :P